# Assets hangs on update index

Tags: assets, error

Assets 2.6
EE 2.10.3

This is a rescue site which I didn't build and I'm trying to get it working on the server. When I go to assets, which I just upgraded to the latest version, and try to update indexes. The page hangs.

I tried adding this to config.php based on another question but no change:

```
$config['assets_site_url'] = '/index.php';
```

I checked the console and see the following:

[image]

Comment: Unexpected identifier... that tends to be an invalid response. It might be possible that ACTion URLs aren't getting through. Anything funny in the `.htaccess` file? Is the CP behind SSL but the front-end not?

Comment: The htaccess only has the recommend stuff to remove index.php and no ssl anywhere.